# Why does Blocklayered indexUrl task uses a truncate by default?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In its configuration page, the module Blocklayered gives 3 urls to call from a crontab to rebuild indexes. One of those urls is used to rebuild the url index.

By default this url is suffixed with the parameter `&truncate=1`. This means that everytime this url is called the `layered_friendly_url` table is truncated and rebuild entirely (which takes a lot of time).

I'm wondering why this is not set to `truncate=0` by default and if I can use it safely in this way? Could I call it with `truncate=0` every day and for example call it with `truncate=1` each month to delete unwanted indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `truncate=0` safely? YES
- If you don't call `truncate=1` then just generate URL that wasn't previously generated. In other words, if you don't use `truncate=1` existing URL will not be regenerated nor updated.

Good luck.